# Compare Opaque or Transactional Kafka spout

Tags: java, message-queue, apache-storm, apache-kafka, trident

What is the difference between `OpaqueTridentKafkaSpout` and `TransactionalTridentKafkaSpout`? When would you use one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not about which one is better, it is about your requirements.
Storm trident topologies deal with `batches` of tuples.

- A `Transactional` storm spout guarantees that batches are non-overlapping and that the same batch will always contains the same set of tuples.
- An `Opaque` storm spout guarantees that batches are non-overlapping, but the contents of a batch may change.

Which to use use is up to your system requirements and semantics.

Comment: Does your comment mean that Opaque spouts are relatively faster than Transactional ones?